Time complexity of Insertion Sort Algorithm, if Array has 'I' number of inversions
I have recently been asked this question and was a little confused as I don't have a good grip on Sorting algorithms.

An array A contains 'I' number of inversions then what is the time
complexity of insertion sort algorithm to sort the array A (of size n)

As the questions says, this is how inversions are defined:

Given an array arr[]. Two elements arr[i] and arr[j] form an inversion
if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

I wanted to understand both the best case and the worst case scenarios of the situation.

Each inversion requires O(n) work on average, and the initial check for an already sorted list is O(n). So I would say the mean complexity is O(n(I+1)).

@IanAbbott: Each inversion requires O(1) swaps to fix. Consider 1 3 4 5 2. This has three inversions: 3 with 2, 4 with 2, and 5 with 2. The algorithm takes 1 3 4 5 as is. When it gets to the 2, it swaps the 5 and the 2, making 1 3 4 2 5 and fixing the 5 2 inversion. Then it swaps the 4 and the 2, making 1 3 2 4 5 and fixing the 4 2 inversion. Then it swaps the 3 and the 2, making 1 2 3 4 5 and fixing the 3 2 inversion. There were three inversions, and three swaps fixed them. The total work is O(n+I).

Re “I wanted to understand both the best case and the worst case scenarios of the situation”: There is no separate best or worst case here. All arrays with n elements and I inversions take exactly a + bn + cI time to execute, as my answer shows. For a given n and I, there is no variation; all cases take the same time.

@EricPostpischil I think I was conflating "number of inversions" with "number of rotations".

Consider an array A with I inversions. Let q(i) be the number of inversions of element Ai with an earlier element, that is, the number of j such that j < i and Aj > Ai.
Summing q(i) for all i indexing the array produces the total number of inversions, since each inversion counted in the sum is distinct from any other and all inversions are counted. Thus sum(q(i)) = I.
Examine the pseudo-code from the Wikipedia page on insertion sort:
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while

The inner while loop contains some constant number c of steps. (The exact number depends on how you count the various subtractions, assignments, comparisons, and swaps, but it is constant.)
For a specific i, the inner loop will be executed q(i) times. This is because, at this point in the execution, the elements from the start to Aj−1 have been sorted, and the number of them that are greater than Ai is qi, so the inner loop must execute exactly qi times to move Ai to its proper place.
Therefore, for all i, the inner loop will be executed exactly sum(q(i)) = I times.
The outer loop is executed n times, and it has some constant number b of steps outside the inner loop. Additionally, there is some constant number a of steps outside the outer loop.
The number of steps executed in this algorithm is exactly a + bn + cI, where a, b, and c are constants capturing the number of steps outside the outer loop, in the outer loop but not in the inner loop, and in the inner loop, respectively. (This includes the fact that these constants can be adjusted to include initial/final comparisons for the loop. For example, while i < length(A) may execute the body of the loop n times but evaluates the comparison n+1 times. One of these comparisons would be included in a, not b.)
a + bn + cI is O(n + I), so the execution time of the algorithm is O(n + I).

I'm sorry, but this is obviously wrong: Insertion sort is generally within O(n^2), so for the worst case of I=n/2 the execution time has to be O(n*I) - it can't be within O(n+I) (despite the fact that I don't find your reasoning logical).

@MetaColon: The time complexity of of insertion sort generally is irrelevant because the question does not ask about insertion sort generally. It asks about insertion sort with a strict constraint, that the number of inversions is known. As my answer demonstrates, the number of inversions tells us exactly how many steps the insertion sort will perform. Note that you are wrong about the worst case being I = n/2. It is I = n•(n−1)/2. The number of inversions is not a number of swaps that were performed to change the element order…

… It counts all the elements that another element moved past. It counts each and every pair of elements that are inverted relative to each other, and elements can be part of multiple such pairs. For example, if we swap 3 and 1 in the sorted sequence 1 2 3, producing 3 2 1, the number of inversions is not one. It is three: 3 is inverted relative to 2, 3 is inverted relative to 1, and 2 is inverted relative to 1. One swap created three inversions. Then consider how the insertion sort algorithm processes the list 3 2 1…

… The algorithm takes 3 as is. When it gets to the 2, it swaps the 3 and the 2, making 2 3 1 and fixing the 3 2 inversion. When it gets to the 1, it swaps the 3 and the 1, making 2 1 3 and fixing the 3 1 inversion. It continues by swapping the 2 and the 1, making 1 2 3 and fixing the 2 1 inversion. There were three inversions, and three swaps fixed them. The total work is O(n+I)…

… The maximum possible number of inversions is n•(n−1)/2, when each element is inverted with respect to each other element, and the list is fully reversed. Then n+I = n+n•(n−1)/2 = n•(n+1)/2. So the worst case of inversion sort is included in this analysis. The question merely asks us to express the complexity as a function of n and the given I, not of n solely. So O(n+I) is correct and includes all possibilities for an insertion sort.

you are right, I was indeed confused with the meaning of inversions.

Insertion sort swaps "inversed" neighbors. So each swap reduces the number of inversions by 1, as it removes that one inversion and doesn't affect any other pairs / inversions. So you do exactly 'I' swaps.
You also get Θ(n) time just from the outer loop. And Θ(n+I) comparisons, as you do one for each element and one more for each inversion you see.
Overall Θ(n+I) complexity.

I suggest clarifying “every swap” to “each swap of adjacent elements.” A swap of non-adjacent elements may add or eliminate multiple inversions. The swaps done in the insertion sort algorithm are only swaps of adjacent elements, but that is not clear without establishing context.

@EricPostpischil That's what "neighbors" means.

@EricPostpischil Did you overlook that or do you disagree?

It’s a suggestion for clarity, not strict correctness. Humans do not instantly deduce every consequence from words nor look ahead to see that “every swap” at their current reading point in the sentence only refers to “neighbors” later in the sentence. It is better to aid reading comprehension through various techniques, such as establishing context first or being explicit about meaning.

@EricPostpischil I felt it was clear already. For me it's really "The key insight is that every swap reduces the number of inversions by 1". That the swaps are of neighbors should already be clear, and then I even still said it anyway. But ok, I've rephrased. Good now? Sadly I couldn't figure out how to keep the "key insight" phrase.
